# Vue Js - Displaying elements using v-for loop in single line (for pagination)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, pagination, vue-router

I am using `v-for` loop to show pagination links -

```
<div v-for="n in this.totalPages">
   <router-link :to="'/top/pages/' + n" @click.native="getPaginatedUser">{{ n }}</router-link>
</div>
```

Each link is getting displayed in new line, like below -

[1](http://#)

[2](http://#)

Is there any way i can display them in single line ? like this -

[1](http://#)
[2](http://#)

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you do it by simple css ? Like set the display property of that div to inline-block ?

Comment: @SwadhIn thanks for the suggestion but i don't want ot use css for this.

Comment: @Derick You can change `<div>` tag to `<span>` because `<div>` by default causes a line break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for each link is displayed in new line is because you are iterating a `div` element which is a block element. You can use an inline element like `span` or Vue specific `template` which won't render any additional markup or you can just iterate the `router` link

```
<router-link
  :to="'/top/pages/' + n"
  @click.native="getPaginatedUser"
  :key="n"
  v-for="n in this.totalPages"
>{{ n }}</router-link>
```

Using `template` instead of `div`.

```
<template v-for="n in this.totalPages">
    <router-link :to="'/top/pages/' + n" @click.native="getPaginatedUser" :key="n">{{ n }}</router-link>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change either the component div to span, or change the style of the div to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

just move the `v-for` to the `router-link` component:

```html
<div>
   <router-link v-for="n in this.totalPages" :key="n" :to="'/top/pages/' + n" @click.native="getPaginatedUser">{{ n }}</router-link>
</div>
```

The `router-link` component will render an `<a>` tag by default, which you can then style via css to get the layout you want.

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  router: new VueRouter()
});
```

```css
a + a { margin-left: 0.3rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <router-link v-for="id in 10" :key="id" :to="'/foo/' + id">{{id}}</router-link>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to template/div and style it with:

```
display: flex;
```

and v-for the router link instead of the div.
It should put your pagination inline!